# MathJax \cancel not working

Tags: support, mathjax

Why isn't this working?
$\require{cancel}$

$ \cancel{x} $

I copied it directly from "Crossing things out" on [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

**EDIT**: It's been fixed

Comment: I have added the required code to the question so that the cancel works. Now all subsequent uses of `\cancel` on this page should work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it says in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13183), the $\LaTeX$ command `\require{cancel}` needs to appear in a MathJax formula before using `\cancel{...}`. I have added it $\underline{\text{here}}\require{cancel}$ so that the cancel in the next paragraph will render properly. Right click on the underlined "here" and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands". You can also do the same with the cancelled $x$ in the next paragraph.

It works if you start with `\require{cancel}`:
$\cancel{x}$

Comment: That actually won't work for me. I think it's a bug or something, because if I do some more MathJax below it, it just starts working! Weird.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work for you? Do you not see the slashed out $x$ in my answer? If I add the requisite code to your question, I see the slashed out $x$.

Comment: I saw that Martin Sleziak added then removed the code to your question, and I saw the slashed out $x$ while it was there.

Comment: @robjohn I have only added ([meta-tag:mathjax]) tag: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/16489/revisions (BTW I see the slashed x rendered differently in your answer and in the question - in the questions instead of slashed x is seed red cancel.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I saw the $\cancel{x}$ rendered properly after the question showed as having been edited by you, so I assumed that you had added the `\require{cancel}` to the question. It reverted to the red cancel before 5 minutes, so I figured you had taken it out. In any case, since the `\require{cancel}` is not in the question, it is not applied there. I can edit the question, but it would make the question seem pointless.

Comment: Woah I guess all this convo happened while I was sleeping. Um yeah I guess it's working now (maybe because RobJohn changed it?). It wasn't working last night.

Comment: @Zack: did you notice the change to your question that I made to enable the `\cancel`?

Comment: The  "\require" thing? Also how did you do a quote in a comment? The carrot ">" symbol doesn't work

Comment: Ok I see. I selected you as my answer thanks

Comment: @Zack: The greater-than-sign should work to quote things. Do you have an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: It's not working here in the comments. <quote >quote

Comment: @Zack: comments are meant to be short. You can only quote lines in a post and the '>' needs to be at the beginning of the line. See [this help page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Comment: @Zack if you mean `\cancel`, that is done by putting the srting in backticks. It has similar background to quotes, though it's different on HTML level, and meant for code fragments.

Comment: @Zack: what 900-sit-ups a day mentions is on the same help page [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code-spans).